# Point of intersection for lines in 3-space

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

I have two lines defined by a starting point ( the line passes this point...) and a direction vector. $$p_1=(10,0,0)$$$$v_1=2i+4j+3k$$$$p_2=(310,480,400)$$$$v_1=-4i-6j-5k$$

I need to ( 1 ) show whether or not these lines intersect, and if they do ( 2 ) what is the point of intersection.

Solution : Since these lines are not parallel on the basis of the direction vectors, we can say that they do indeed intersect. In order to find the point of intersection, we must first write these lines in vector parametric form - which gives us a system of equations

$$10+2t=310-4s
$$$$4t=480-6s
$$$$3t=400-5s
$$

From here, we just solve the parameters $s$ and $t$ and use them to find the co-ordinates of our intersection point. Solving for s and t, however, I get $s = 60$ and $t = 30$ which satisfies the first two equations, but no the third one. Is there an error in calculation or does this say something about our problem?

Comment: Method is fine. First solve for s and t in the first two equations. Now substitute those values into the third equation. Is the third equality then true? Think about what that might mean if it is/is not true.

Comment: I got s = 60 and t = 30, the first two equations are true but the third is not. I think that might say something about the z co-ordinate. Not sure what though.

Comment: Beware: in 3-space it is not true that two non-parallel lines must intersect, there are also [skew lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines).

Comment: The equations are not consistent then. You have assumed the lines meet, found s and t but then the third equation contradicts their values. Your assumption must be wrong then, they cannot meet. If the third equation were consistent you could find x, y and z in terms of s and t where they meet.